# Terraform: apply only one tf file

Tags: terraform

I have my security groups in a `securitygroup.tf` file.

In the same dir there are plenty of other resource descriptions (rds, ec2 etc).

Is there a way to perform a `terraform apply --auto-approve` **only** for my `securitygroups.tf`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Not really. The standard way to work around this though is to use eg:

```
terraform apply -target=aws_security_group.my_sg
```

but that's only going to apply one security group at a time, so will get tedious if you have a lot of them. You can, however, target multiple resources in one command:

```
terraform apply -target=aws_security_group.my_sg -target=aws_security_group.my_2nd_sg
```

However, there are potentially a couple of workarounds:

- **The `-target` parameter respects dependencies.**

  This means if you were to eg. `-target=aws_instance.my_server` and that instance had, say, five security groups attached to it via interpolation, changes to those security groups *should* be included in the plan (I haven't thoroughly tested this, but I believe this is how it works).

  That is a bit messy though, as you probably don't want to touch an instance. A safer alternative might be using something like a [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) to provide a target for the security groups, but again I haven't tried this (there might be another 'safe' resource you could rely on, though?).
- **Create a module.**

  You can target a [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/modules.html) just like you can target a plain resource (be sure to include the quotes around the target name):

  ```
   terraform apply -target="module.my_security_groups"
  ```

  Inside this module, you could define all of your security groups - just like you would have outside of the module. As well as being able to target it directly, this also makes it easier for you to re-use the same set of security groups for other infrastructure, if you ever need to.

Comment: `terraform state list` is a great way to find the available resources

Answer (score 14):

If you organize your code by modules, you could apply terraform only on a module, eg :

```
# securitygroup.tf
module "securitygroup" {
  source = "git@github.com:user/securitygroup-terraform-module.git?ref=master"
}

$ tf apply -target=module.securitygroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Using terraform module is preferred, but if you really have to run terraform apply against a single file, I made this bash script to generate terraform apply command against all targets and modules in one file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ -z "$@" ]]; then
  echo "Missing file input arguments"
  exit 1
fi

echo "terraform apply \\"
for FILE in "$@"
do
  RESOURCE=$(sed -n 's/resource "\([^"]*\)" "\([^"]*\)".*/-target=\1.\2 \\/gp' $FILE)
  MODULE=$(sed -n 's/module "\([^"]*\)".*/-target=module.\1 \\/gp' $FILE)
  if [[ -z "$RESOURCE" ]] && [[ -z "$MODULE" ]]; then
    echo "Cannot detect terraform resource and module in $FILE"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [[ ! -z "$RESOURCE" ]]; then
    echo -e $"$RESOURCE"
  fi
  if [[ ! -z "$MODULE" ]]; then
    echo -e $"$MODULE"
  fi
done
echo "-refresh=true"
```

I'm not really a bash expert, but it was tested to work on Mac.

EDIT: The sed command assumes that the resources and modules are formatted nicely according to `terraform fmt` like so:

```sh
resource "aws_eip" "my_public_ip" {
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_server" {
}

module "my_module" {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, **Terraform** doesn't have the feature to apply **a specific .tf file**. **Terraform** applies **all .tf files** in the same directory.

But you can apply **the specific code** with **comment out** and **uncomment**. For example, you have 2 .tf files **"1st.tf"** and **"2nd.tf"** in the same directory to create the resources for **GCP(Google Cloud Platform)**:

[image]

Then, **"1st.tf"** has this code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-113738"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

And **"2nd.tf"** has this code below:

```js
resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
  display_name = "Service Account 1"
  account_id   = "service-account-1"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
  display_name = "Service Account 2"
  account_id   = "service-account-2"
}
```

Now, first, you want to only apply the code in **"1st.tf"** so you need to **comment out** the code in **"2nd.tf"**:

**1st.tf**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-113738"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

**2nd.tf (Comment Out)**:

```py
# resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
#   display_name = "Service Account 1"
#   account_id   = "service-account-1"
# }

# resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
#   display_name = "Service Account 2"
#   account_id   = "service-account-2"
# }
```

Then, you apply:

```html
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Next, additionally, you want to apply the code in **"2nd.tf"** so you need to **uncomment** the code in **"2nd.tf"**:

**1st.tf**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-113738"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

**2nd.tf (Uncomment)**:

```py
resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
  display_name = "Service Account 1"
  account_id   = "service-account-1"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
  display_name = "Service Account 2"
  account_id   = "service-account-2"
}
```

Then, you apply:

```html
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

This way, you can apply **the specific code** with **comment out** and **uncomment**.

Comment: Welcome to DevOps.SE.  How is this method better than the accepted answer here?

Comment: I would not recommend commenting and uncommenting since it violates infrastructure as a code approach, thereby developers end up in a situation where `*.tf` specification differs from real state

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it's possible. [Here is the code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/config/import_tree.go) to load config files and it loads all *.tf files from current directory (or a specified one) and there is nothing there to limit the configuration to a single file.

Comment: Other answers are here which show how this is possible.  At least one of them was here before you posted your answer.  Do you stand by this answer?